# Good equidistant Canada-wide projection?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, canada

I'm trying to map several thousand points across Canada, and find nearest neighbours for each point. I've figured out how to do all of this in QGIS using the Distance Matrix tool, but my projection was WGS84 so I'm getting distances in degrees. Some searching of StackExchange has led me to realize that I need an (ideally equidistant) projection that calculates distances in metres.

Anyone have any suggestions for a CRS that would work in this scenario? I realize there's going to be some error, but as long as it's not a crazy amount I should be okay…

Comment: Lamberts Conformal Conic is best for Canada http://www.statcan.gc.ca/pub/92-195-x/2011001/other-autre/mapproj-projcarte/m-c-eng.htm (and in Metres)

Comment: You can use [Projection Wizard](http://projectionwizard.org/) to define own projection based on specified area and distortion and then get libproj definition.